# How to quantify the Abundance of a particular gene in Bacteria and Archaea?

Tags: phylogenetics, experiment

For 16s rDNA metagenomic analysis, do I need to do the following steps?

> DNA extraction-> Purification-> PCR amplification-> Clone -> Pick every single
>   colony-> PCR amplify -> Sequence -> Phylogenetic Analysis

For the abundance of a particular gene abundance, what steps do I need to follow? Is it necessary to clone?

`

Comment: 16S rDNA? You mean 16S ribosomal RNA, right? If yes then no you don't need to do a library in bacterial clones anymore. With next generation sequencing technologies the library is made *In-Vitro* followed by PCR-like step (e.g. [Illumina Nextera XT kit](http://www.illumina.com/products/nextera_xt_dna_sample_prep_kit.html)). What you would do is RNA extraction -> Reverse-transcription -> PCR amplification -> library building using a kit -> Sequencing -> Phylogenetic analysis.